# How can you draw a bezier curve given four points with wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, bezier, spline

It appears to me that the [DC](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DC-class.html)'s only support for curves of any sort is with splines. Are there any libraries that add bezier functionality, or is there a way to convert a bezier curve into a spline?

Comment: Hm ... what are you trying to do? Asymptote is amazing at graphics. Check out: http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/BezierSurface.asy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little googling, I think I'll go with [wx.GraphicsContext](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.GraphicsContext-class.html), which supports [wx.GraphicsPath](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.GraphicsPath-class.html). It appears to have exactly what I need, in addition to anti-aliasing (according to [this page](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/WxPythonGraphicsContext))

Comment: Good idea.  It's the new way to draw in wxpython.

Answer (score 2):

Given 4 control points, the formula for the associated cubic Bezier curve is [not hard to compute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). Once you calculate a set of points on the curve, you could use [`DC.DrawLines`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DC-class.html#DrawLines) to draw it.

There is a python implementation for calculating points on generalized Bezier curves (shameless plug) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246525/how-can-i-draw-a-bezier-curve-using-pythons-pil). It's generalized in the sense that it can accept an arbitrary number of control points (>2) as input to `make_bezier`. If you want only the 4-control point version, you can cut out `pascal_row` entirely and replace

```
combinations=pascal_row(n-1)
```

with

```
combinations=(1,3,3,1)
```